# Tabulator: component.getComponent is not a function

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Tabular in a Next/React environment and I occasionally get the following when clicking a button that's rendered via a custom formatter:

`component.getComponent is not a function`

The button/custom formatter:

```
const EditButton = () => {
  const editor = document.createElement('button');
  editor.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
  editor.style.color = '#FFF';
  editor.innerHTML = 'Edit';
  editor.style.width = '100%';
  return editor;
}
```

The button event:

```
const handleEditButtonClick = (e, c) => {
  const el = e.target as HTMLButtonElement;
  const data = c.getRow().getData();
  console.log(el, data);
}
```

Tabulator is initialized via a useEffect:

```
  let el = React.createRef();
  let tabulator: typeof Tabulator | null = null;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (el.current) {
      tabulator = new Tabulator(el.current, {
        data: [...productsData()],
        columns: columns,
      });
    }
  }, [el]);
```

And rendered:

```
  return (
    <div ref={el} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
  );
```

The column:

```
{ formatter: EditButton, cellClick: handleEditButtonClick }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say if this is the case without looking at the full component code, but in my case column/row options were being calculated within the component. This was causing the options to get recalculated on renders, which I am assuming was causing the table to re-render too. This I believe caused things like `c.getRow().getData();` to fail because the `c` from the previous render was gone.

Just putting the options calculations inside useMemo hooks solved the problem.